# How do I access individual nodes in an RDD[Iterator[scala.xml.Node]]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD that is of

```
t: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Iterator[scala.xml.Node]] = MapPartitionsRDD[23]
```

When using `map` such as below to access individual node I get an error

```
scala> t.map(l => l(0))

<console>:41: error: Iterator[scala.xml.Node] does not take parameters
              t.map(l => l(0))
```

Is there way to get individual nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access an *Iterator* with number index; You can use `slice` with `next` to access the *nth* element in an iterator as `i.slice(n,n+1).next`:

```
val rdd = spark.range(3).rdd.map(_ => Iterator(2,3,4))
// rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Iterator[Int]] = MapPartitionsRDD[19] at map at <console>:23

// to access the first element in each iterator
rdd.map(l => l.slice(0,1).next).collect
// res24: Array[Int] = Array(2, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Or just convert it to a `Seq` first with `l.toSeq`, then access it by index. Depends on how many different indices you will be accessing whether this is worth it. And which order - because using `slice` consumes (some of) the iterator so you can't get a value the same way again.